# How to add Search form/Advanced search form view to advanced forum pages?

Tags: 7, nodes, views

I found two things in Advanced forum.

**1.** Advanced forum provides the views, one of which is advanced forum search as shown in the following image, which provide the specific search on the forum.

[image: Advanced forum search view]

**2.** But it is a separate link, and totally separate page, if it will be under the title of the advanced forum topic and on every forum discussion page, it will be very suitable for visitors. As shown in this image.

[image: needed search form at top, under the title]

Now, how to add that advanced forum box and advanced option selection box provided in views under the forum title? **I mean all on all the pages of forum except the first main page. Very Thanks.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to display the exposed filters in a block, and then display that block on single forum node pages.

Here's how to do that:

1. Edit the Forum Search view: `/admin/structure/views/view/advanced_forum_search/edit`.
2. Under "Exposed form" -> "Exposed form in block" choose "Yes".
3. Save the view.
4. Navigate to `/admin/structure/block`.
5. Enable the "Exposed form: advanced_forum_search-page" block, and show it for example in the "Content" area and only for "Forum topic" nodes. You can change this to your liking of course.

Users now can use this form from single forum nodes, and submitting it will take them to the search page.

#### Update

If you want to make this available in your templates and position it within other elements, you'll have to edit the `template.php` of your theme add a `hook_preprocess_X()` implementation.

Choice depends on the template you want to add the form to. For example:

- `hook_preprocess_node()` - to make the form available in `node.tpl.php`
- `hook_preprocess_page()` - to make the form available in `page.tpl.php`
- `hook_preprocess_html()` - to make the form available in `html.tpl.php`

Here's the code:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_REPLACE_THIS(&$variables) {
  // Load the view and generate the search form.
  //
  // You can have any dynamic conditions here (e.g. limit to some content types
  // and so on).
  $view = views_get_view('advanced_forum_search');
  $view->set_display('page');
  $view->init_handlers();
  $form_state = array(
    'view' => $view,
    'display' => $view->display_handler->display,
    'exposed_form_plugin' => $view->display_handler->get_plugin('exposed_form'),
    'method' => 'get',
    'rerender' => TRUE,
    'no_redirect' => TRUE,
  );
  $variables['search_form'] = drupal_build_form('views_exposed_form', $form_state);
}
```

Then in your `.tpl.php` file you would use this code to display the form:

```
<?php print render($search_form); ?>
```

Note that this way the visibility settings in admin won't be applied.

Comment: Hmmm...this is working...

Comment: Is there any way that search form can be placed besides the "New Topic" as shown in the image above? I understood that, this process is displaying the the search form view as a block and that block we are placing to the main-content. This way  it can be placed either to the top or bottom of main page.

Comment: That depends on your CSS. You could also make it available through a `hook_preprocess_whatever()` function, and then invoke it in the template. Will update my answer shortly.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Well...I did not get few things, If you please can put light on that.  I am little familiar with preprocess. Why you want to implement in `page() or node() or html()` tpl file. why not to the `.tpl.php` file where the the code of `New topic` is there. Why not in `advanced-forum.naked.topic-list-outer-view.tpl.php` which has the code of `<?php if ($node_create_list): ?><div class="forum-node-create-links forum-node-create-links-top"><?php print $node_create_list ?></div>
  <?php endif; ?>` which prints `New topic`. And put that tpl file in theme's templates folder.